# InvalidConfigurationException in SecurityExtension.php line 429: No authentication listener registered for firewall "secured_area"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new symfony user and follow the [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#logging-out). 
 My current task is to add logout script but unfortunately it gives me this error:

```
InvalidConfigurationException in SecurityExtension.php line 429: No authentication listener registered for firewall "secured_area".
```

My security.yml file looks like this:

```
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:
                        password: $2a$12$LCY0MefVIEc3TYPHV9SNnuzOfyr2p/AXIGoQJEDs4am4JwhNz/jli
                        roles: 'ROLE_USER'
                    admin:
                        password: $2a$12$cyTWeE9kpq1PjqKFiWUZFuCRPwVyAZwm4XzMZ1qPUFl7/flCM3V0G
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            # ...
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

    access_control:
        # require ROLE_ADMIN for /admin*
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you show all code from `secured_area:`?
I think problem in that you use same routes for logOut and pattern. Please, try change

```
logout:
    path: /logout
    target: /login
```

If it's help, let me know

**UPDATE**

it must look like this

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
    provider: chain_provider
    form_login:
        login_path: loginAction
        check_path: checkAction
        csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
        default_target_path: userRedirectAction
    logout:
       path: /logout
       target: /login
```

Comment: There is no pattern added

Comment: @yakobabada try this. Change `loginAction` and `checkAction` in router.yml for your routes

Comment: I updated as you told me, the problem is solved but appeared a different issue that is the user still logged in. But I in login I use http_basic.

Comment: try  `<a href="{{ path('/logout') }}">Exit</a>`. How you logOut?

Comment: I did by access '/logout' but the user didn't logout

Comment: thanks a lot for you efforts. I found the solution :)